# oracle sql loader: value larger than specified precision allowed for this column

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

I have text delimited file and try to insert to oracle database use sql loader. The content of my file like this.

According to **mathguy** reply, this is the full of my text file content

```
 store |    datetime    | termnmbr | transnmbr |      mdesc       | mediaamnt |     accountnmbr
 305   | 12/07/16 10:07 |        1 |6070000449 |             CASH |     50000 |
 305   | 12/07/16 10:07 |        1 |6070000448 |             CASH |    100000 |
 305   | 12/07/16 10:07 |        1 |6070000447 |             CASH |     50000 |
 305   | 12/07/16 10:07 |        1 |6070000445 |             CASH |    209000 |
 305   | 12/07/16 12:07 |        1 |6070000430 |             CASH |    100000 |
 305   | 12/07/16 12:07 |        1 |6070000429 |             CASH |     50000 |
(6 rows)
```

My control file

```
OPTIONS (SILENT=(FEEDBACK),SKIP=1)
LOAD DATA 
INFILE *
APPEND 
INTO TABLE "MKG_MED_N"
WHEN (1:1) <> '('
FIELDS TERMINATED BY "|" 
TRAILING NULLCOLS
(
STORE_CODE,
TRANS_DATE "to_date(:TRANS_DATE, 'DD/MM/YY HH24:MI')",
POS_NO,
TRANS_NO "substr(trim(:TRANS_NO),1,10)",
MED_DESC "trim(:MED_DESC)", 
MED_AMOUNT,
MED_ACC_NO "trim(TRANSLATE (:MED_ACC_NO, 'x'||CHR(10)||CHR(13), 'x'))",
)
```

The problem is, i've got error

```
Record 2: Rejected - Error on table "MKG_MED_N", column TRANS_NO.
ORA-01438: value larger than specified precision allowed for this column.
```

This come from log file as asked by **Arkadiusz Łukasiewicz**

```
SQL*Loader: Release 11.2.0.1.0 - Production on Wed Jul 13 14:35:43 2016

Copyright (c) 1982, 2009, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

Control File:   /u07/mkg/script/MkgMed20160712.305.ctl
Data File:      /u07/mkg/1607/MkgMed20160712.305
  Bad File:     /u07/mkg/bad/MkgMed20160712.305.bad
  Discard File: /u07/mkg/discard/MkgMed20160712.305.dis
 (Allow all discards)

Number to load: ALL
Number to skip: 1
Errors allowed: 999
Bind array:     64 rows, maximum of 256000 bytes
Continuation:    none specified
Path used:      Conventional
Silent options: FEEDBACK
Table "MKG_MED_N", loaded when 1:1 != 0X28(character '(')
Insert option in effect for this table: APPEND
TRAILING NULLCOLS option in effect

   Column Name                  Position   Len  Term Encl Datatype
------------------------------ ---------- ----- ---- ---- ---------------------
STORE_CODE                          FIRST     *   |       CHARACTER
TRANS_DATE                           NEXT     *   |       CHARACTER
    SQL string for column : "to_date(:TRANS_DATE, 'DD/MM/YY HH24:MI')"
POS_NO                               NEXT     *   |       CHARACTER
TRANS_NO                             NEXT     *   |       CHARACTER
    SQL string for column : "substr(trim(:TRANS_NO),1,10)"
MED_DESC                             NEXT     *   |       CHARACTER
    SQL string for column : "trim(:MED_DESC)"
MED_AMOUNT                           NEXT     *   |       CHARACTER
MED_ACC_NO                           NEXT     *   |       CHARACTER
    SQL string for column : "trim(TRANSLATE (:MED_ACC_NO, 'x'||CHR(10)||CHR(13), 'x'))"

Record 1: Rejected - Error on table "MKG_MED_N", column TRANS_NO.
ORA-01438: value larger than specified precision allowed for this column

Record 2: Rejected - Error on table "MKG_MED_N", column TRANS_NO.
ORA-01438: value larger than specified precision allowed for this column
```

Column TRANS_NO on my table defined as Number(11,0).

As asked by Finbarr O'B, this from bad file:

```
 305   | 12/07/16 10:07 |        1 |6070000449 |             CASH |     50000 |
 305   | 12/07/16 10:07 |        1 |6070000448 |             CASH |    100000 |
 305   | 12/07/16 10:07 |        1 |6070000447 |             CASH |     50000 |
 305   | 12/07/16 10:07 |        1 |6070000445 |             CASH |    209000 |
 305   | 12/07/16 12:07 |        1 |6070000430 |             CASH |    100000 |
 305   | 12/07/16 12:07 |        1 |6070000429 |             CASH |     50000 |
```

Anyone can help me? Thanks before.

Comment: It sounds like you have at least one "transnmbr" that's more than 11 digits. Perhaps you can write just a short code fragment to pick out the rows where that happens. Or, you can go to your table and change the column precision, see if that fixes it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply mathguy. I can not found "transnmbr" row with more than 11 digits. I add the full of my file content on my question.

Comment: The compiler doesn't lie. Some value in transnmbr is not correct. Try substr them to max 11 digits and convert it to number before insert.

Comment: Add everything from log file till first rejected line "Record 2: Rejected". And encoding of data file

Comment: Marcus H: yeah, i know, that's why i feel so confuse. Arkadiusz Łukasiewicz: i edit my post to make it clearer.

Comment: Is it necessary to 'substr(trim))' the TRANS_NO field? Have you tried to specify this in the CTL file as 'INTEGER EXTERNAL' instead? i.e. `TRAILING NULLCOLS
(
STORE_CODE,
TRANS_DATE "to_date(:TRANS_DATE, 'DD/MM/YY HH24:MI')",
POS_NO,
TRANS_NO INTEGER EXTERNAL,` Also, what rows have been logged into the MkgMed20160712.305.bad file?

Comment: Finbarr O'B: just try my luck :) i've added content of MkgMed20160712.305.bad on my post.